# use or in if statement in batch script

Tags: batch-file, cmd, scripting

I am creating a batch script where I have to compare versions and then proceed with the installation. I am getting error @ when I use `or` (`||`) in `if`. How do I compare two conditions in one `if`? I tried using a for loop by creating a list of values and then comparing. This is also giving me an error.

```
@echo off

set "python_ver=Python 3.7"

set "python_major=(not found)"
set "python_minor=(not found)"

FOR /f "tokens=1,2 delims=." %%a IN ("%python_ver%") do set 
python_major=%%a & set python_minor=%%b

FOR /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%a IN ("%python_major%") do set 
python_major=%%b 

if %python_major%==3 (
    if %python_minor% LSS 5 or  if  %python_minor% GTR 6 (
        echo version not supported. should be 3.5 or 3.6
    ) else (
        echo go to install
    )
) else (
    echo Please update your python
)
```

Comment: is `%phyton_major%` really meant to be `Python 3`? You should better use token 2 and 3 with delims= dot and space:  `FOR /f "tokens=2,3 delims=. " %%a in ...`

Comment: [The Windows command prompt is *NOT* a DOS prompt!](https://scalibq.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/the-windows-command-prompt-is-not-a-dos-prompt/)

Comment: `if` can't do things like `AND` or `OR`

Comment: Try `if %python_minor% LSS 5 (echo version not supported. should be 3.5 or 3.6) else (if %python_minor% GTR 5 (echo go to install))`

Comment: this is working fine......... but when i add or to second if it shows error . I have to add another condtion that id %python_minor% is gtr 6 then also it should not allow.                  
 if %python_major%==3 (
    if %python_minor% LSS 5  (
        echo version not supported. should be 3.5 or 3.6
    ) else (
        echo go to install
    )
) else (
    echo Please update your python
)